# country_select gem not working with fields_for nested form in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Does anyone know how to get country_select to work with fields_for?

https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select

It doesn't seem to accept the model prefix, as do the other form field helpers in the nested form.

If there is no way to make it work, is there another way to quickly/easily get a country selector field in my form?

Thanks.

Comment: Let me know how you are using it .

Comment: I have a parent form_for (account) and a nested child fields_for (address).  All of the fields in the fields_for look like: address.text_field :street, etc.  I tried using address.country_select("address", "country_name") and just country_select("address", "country_name") but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this code works:

```
<%= f.country_select :country,  :style=>'width:100px;'%>
```

Cheers mate !

Comment: if u have  defined fields for as address use address.country_select instead of f.country_select